# cannot post to API using Curl in PHP

Tags: php, curl

Am using the code below to post to API using curl, but am having issues/error

**"HTTP/1.1 400 Bad Request Content-Type: application/json Date: Mon, 04 Sep 2017 05:40:40 GMT Server: Apigee Router Content-Length: 231 Connection: keep-alive {"developerMessage":"The required parameter(s) client_id,client_secret,grant_type not present in the request","userMessage":"","errorCode":"AUTH-008","more info":""}
"**

it says some parameters are not present while i have supplied all the parameters needed in the code below

```
$url ="mysite.com/authentication/v1/gettoken?client_id=T9hq3zS1CedgVb1mAYECM&client_secret=03hRRTz&grant_type=authorization_code&code=vWnbF8G3UhvMe66-R37lM117LcxjeBLsFwEeLBAy&redirect_uri=mysite.com/testing.php";

$header = array("content-type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded");
$ch = curl_init();
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, 1);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, $header);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_ENCODING, "");
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_CUSTOMREQUEST, 'POST');
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_USERAGENT, 'Mozilla/4.0 (compatible; MSIE 6.0; Windows NT 5.1; SV1; .NET CLR 1.0.3705; .NET CLR 1.1.4322)');

echo $retValue = curl_exec($ch);
echo '<br><br>';

//$response = json_decode(curl_exec($ch));
//$ee       = curl_getinfo($ch);
//print_r($ee);

print_r($retValue);
```

Comment: According to the API message, you are missing some credentials. Where is the API expected to read the credentials? Have you tried to send those in the request headers?

Answer (score 0):

It looks like the API is waiting a JSON string, so try this:

```
$headers = array ( "Content-Type: application/json" );
curl_setopt ( $ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, $headers );
```

And since you are using POST, you should probably send something:

```
$json = '{
    "fields": {
        "customfield": [
            "100"
        ]
    }
}';
curl_setopt ( $ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $json );
```

If you need to authenticate:

```
$username = "test";
$password = "test";
curl_setopt ( $ch, CURLOPT_USERPWD, $username . ":" . $password );
```

Comment: None of the above solution works. This what am trying to do. I have created an app with autodesk.com here https://developer.autodesk.com. Am trying to authenticate my app by using their 3 legged authentication login as can be seen in the link below https://developer.autodesk.com/en/docs/oauth/v2/tutorials/get-3-legged-token/. The first steps involves getting the token in the form codes, the second step involves passing it in a curl to authenticate the users and thats where am having issues

Comment: Maybe like this:
`curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, "https://developer.api.autodesk.com/authentication/v1/gettoken");
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, "client_id=obQDn8P0GanGFQha4ngKKVWcxwyvFAGE&client_secret=eUruM8HRyc7BAQ1e&grant_type=authorization_code&code=wroM1vFA4E-Aj241-quh_LVjm7UldawnNgYEHQ8I&redirect_uri=http://sampleapp.com/oauth/callback");
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, 1);

$headers = array();
$headers[] = "Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded";
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, $headers);`